# pandas - apply function to current row against all other rows

Tags: matrix, pandas

I am utilizing pandas to create a dataframe that appears as follows:

```
ratings = pandas.DataFrame({
    'article_a':[1,1,0,0],
    'article_b':[1,0,0,0],
    'article_c':[1,0,0,0],
    'article_d':[0,0,0,1],
    'article_e':[0,0,0,1]
},index=['Alice','Bob','Carol','Dave'])
```

I would like to compute another matrix from this input one that will compare each row against all other rows.  Let's assume for example the computation was a function to find the length of the intersection set, I'd like an output DataFrame with the `len(intersection(Alice,Bob))`, `len(intersection(Alice,Carol))`, `len(intersection(Alice,Dave))` in the first row,  with each row following that format against the others.  Using this example input, the output matrix would be 4x3:

```
len(intersection(Alice,Bob)),len(intersection(Alice,Carol)),len(intersection(Alice,Dave))
len(intersection(Bob,Alice)),len(intersection(Bob,Carol)),len(intersection(Bob,Dave))
len(intersection(Carol,Alice)),len(intersection(Carol,Bob)),len(intersection(Carol,Dave))
len(intersection(Dave,Alice)),len(intersection(Dave,Bob)),len(intersection(Dave,Carol))
```

Is there a named method for this kind of function based computation in pandas?  What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of a named method, but I have a one-liner.

```
In [21]: ratings.apply(lambda row: ratings.apply(
... lambda x: np.equal(row, x), 1).sum(1), 1)
Out[21]: 
       Alice  Bob  Carol  Dave
Alice      5    3      2     0
Bob        3    5      4     2
Carol      2    4      5     3
Dave       0    2      3     5
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  I've been searching for this all over.

Answer (score 1):

@Dan Allan solution is 'right', here's a slightly different way of approaching the problem

```
In [26]: ratings
Out[26]: 
       article_a  article_b  article_c  article_d  article_e
Alice          1          1          1          0          0
Bob            1          0          0          0          0
Carol          0          0          0          0          0
Dave           0          0          0          1          1

In [27]: ratings.apply(lambda x: (ratings.T.sub(x,'index')).sum(),1)
Out[27]: 
       Alice  Bob  Carol  Dave
Alice      0   -2     -3    -1
Bob        2    0     -1     1
Carol      3    1      0     2
Dave       1   -1     -2     0
```

Comment: Interesting. I replaced my list comprehension with a slightly nicer nested apply. But this is even more compact. I wonder if ``np.equal`` can be worked into it....