# Is there some other way to create row-wise data that's derived from all other rows, in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

As part of a Data Science course at uni, we were asked to work out the most remote capital city.  I'm asking this question here because I'm not happy with my answer, but I wasn't given a better alternative after submission.

As I understand it, the task requires 3 parts:

1. Acquire capital city location data
2. Create distance function for lat/long pairs
3. Use pandas to find the minimum distance from a capital city to any other

The first 2 tasks where trivial.  However I struggled to find a way to solve the 3rd task [without resorting to iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas).  The distance function requires a pair of lat/long values.  I need to figure out a way to apply this function to each row, for each other row.

```
capitals['closest'] = inf
for idx, row_x in capitals.iterrows():
    capitals.at[idx,'closest'] = capitals.apply(lambda row_y: 
                                 haversine(row_x['lat'],row_x['lng'],row_y['lat'],row_y['lng'])
                                 if row_x['city'] != row_y['city']
                                 else inf
                                , axis=1).min()
```

Is there a way to nest calls to the DataFrame `apply` method?  Is there some other way to create row-wise data that's derived from all other rows?

**Edit:** Here my final answer, which *previously* used an iterator (see commit history), but has since been updated with the better solution:
https://github.com/maccaroo/worldcities/blob/main/world_cities.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the 'Similar questions' search as I was about to post, but I feel my answer is different enough to warrant a post.

First, here's the [post which (mostly) answered by question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924421/pandas-apply-function-to-current-row-against-all-other-rows).  However I kept getting this error:  `KeyError: ('city', 'occurred at index city', 'occurred at index city')`

[This article](https://medium.com/@danalindquist/why-isnt-my-pandas-apply-working-try-axis-1-7e16b9960bbe) got me over the line.  The solution to that was the `axis=1` arguments, which tell `apply` to use the column rather than the row index when processing the data.

Here's my final code:

```
capitals['closest'] = inf
capitals['closest'] = capitals.apply(lambda row:
    capitals.apply(lambda x: 
                   haversine(row['lat'],row['lng'],x['lat'],x['lng']) 
                   if row['city'] != x['city'] 
                   else inf
              ,axis=1)
    ,axis=1).min()
```